# Which JSF component to display a text area in non editing mode?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, textarea, editor, cleditor

I would like to display a text area which is used in two modes :

- A modification mode, using p:editor
- A  visualization mode, where only text area is visible.

Which component would be the best choice for this visualization mode ? I have tried with :

- p : editor : I don’t want the toolbar to be visible. It seems it is not possible to hide it.
- p:outputTextarea : html tags generated by p:editor are visible in the textarea
- h: outputText : rendering  is a little different from that of p:editor and above all, as there is no vertical  scroll bar, the text overflows its container.

I have also tried with p:outputTextarea for both editing and visualization modes, but I would be interessed in further tools available in p:editor.

Any idea ?

```
<p:panel id="panelDG">
        <p:dataGrid id="pdatagrid1" layout="grid" value="#{ib.bloc.groups}" var="group" columns="#{ib.bloc.groupsSize}" rowIndexVar="status">
             <!-- other components -->
               <p:panel styleClass="panel-textarea">
                   <s:account>  
                         <p:editor id="editor1" value="#{ib.textArea1}" rendered="#{status == 0}" maxlength="4000" controls="bold italic underline strikethrough bullets outdent indent alignleft center alignright justify undo redo"  />
                         <p:editor id="editor2" value="#{ib.textArea2}" rendered="#{status == 1}" maxlength="4000" controls="bold italic underline strikethrough bullets outdent indent alignleft center alignright justify undo redo"  />
                         <p:editor id="editor3" value="#{ib.textArea3}" rendered="#{status == 2}" maxlength="4000" controls="bold italic underline strikethrough bullets outdent indent alignleft center alignright justify undo redo"  />
                         <h:panelGrid >
                                <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{ib.modifyGroupText(group)}"  icon="ui-icon-disk" />
                         </h:panelGrid>
                   </s:account>
                   <s:guest>
                          <h:outputText value="#{group.textArea}" escape="false"></h:outputText>
                   </s:guest>
             </p:panel>
       </p:dataGrid>
</p:panel

.panel-textarea{
height: 500px; 
}
```

Comment: *"rendering is a little different from that of p:editor and above all, as there is no vertical scroll bar, the text overflows its container"* Just throw in some CSS to align out it?

Comment: Do you mean choosing a bigger value for height in panel-textarea class or something other ? I don't want a big value. Moreover, I would like the page to be responsive. On a mobile screen, the height should be even greater.

Comment: _"p : editor : I don’t want the toolbar to be visible. It seems it is not possible to hide it."_: What did you try? **easy** to hide with css

Comment: And with the disabled attribute you can prevent editing... I fail to see your problem.

Comment: I don't only want to prevent editing, I want only the text is visible. I have looked for an attribute that may hide the toolbar. I don't know how to do that with css, especially with primefaces css to override.

Comment: Use a browser developer tool, take a look at the generated html and you'll see it is very easy to hide the toolbar with css. Very easy.

Comment: If you don't want to show the toolbar why you want to use p:editor in first place?

Comment: because I want the user to be able to use fonctionnalities, like putting the text in bold characters, indentation..., which is not possible with p:outputTextarea. But users without modification permission don't have to see the toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide the toolbar of `<p:editor>` because a user don't have editing permissions you can simply use css.

**Facelet**

```
<p:editor styleClass="#{!login.editAccess ? 'hideToolbar' : ''}" disabled="#{!login.editAccess}" ... />
```

**CSS**

```
.hideToolbar .ui-editor-toolbar {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: Why not improve the original answer? And this answer is not ok either... Just hiding the toolbar does not make it non-editable... You should use the `disabled` attribute of the `p:editor` to (as can also be read in the comments ;-))

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I had not seen the .ui-editor-toolbar class !

Otherwise, to avoid text overflow when using h:outputText :

```
.h-outputText{
display:block !important;
overflow-y: auto !important;
height: 400px !important;
}
```

Thanks for all answers